# Rails scope lambda excluding fields with null values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, join, scope

I have a scope which looks for call records where call_status is open and unit_id is nil.

```
scope :unassigned_calls, where(:call_status => "open", :unit_id => nil).order("id ASC")
```

I've recently setup a has_many relationship where unit_id is no longer used on the call model instead a field called unit_ids on the call_unit model join table.

How can I express the scope or lambda to where it includes the unit_ids from the join table?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe AREL allows you to call outer joins. Try writing out the SQL

```
scope :unassigned_calls, joins("left outer join call_unit on call.id=call_unit.call_id").where("call_unit.unit_id is null").order("id ASC")
```

I assuming here that the join table has a call_id column, this may not be exact but hopefully it will provide you with the necessary framework

Comment: If you are doing outer joins often and don't like writing SQL fragments like the one above, you can use [squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel), which gives you the flexibility to do something like: ``` scope :unassgined_calls, joins{call_unit.outer ```